# Link attachment to record which doesn't have an id

Tags: apex, visualforce

Good day how can one attach a file to a new object, which of course doesn't yet have an id. I am creating a form which will have attachments to it.  Please find the code below which saves the attachment to a record with a specific id. How can one get the id before one can actually save the record?

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="UploadFileAttach">
<apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Upload Attachment">
        <apex:inputFile style="width:100%" id="fileToUpload" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Upload/Save" action="{!UploadFile}"/>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class UploadFileAttach
{
public Id recId
{    get;set;    }

public UploadFileAttach(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
{
   recId = ctlr.getRecord().Id;     
}

public string fileName 
{    get;set;    }

public Blob fileBody 
{    get;set;    }

public PageReference UploadFile()
{
    PageReference pgRef;
    if(fileBody != null && fileName != null)
    {
      Attachment myAttachment  = new Attachment();
      myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
      myAttachment.Name = fileName;
      myAttachment.ParentId = recId;
      insert myAttachment;
       pgRef = new PageReference('/' + myAttachment.Id);
       pgRef.setRedirect(true);
       return pgRef;
    }
    return null;
   }    
}
```

Comment: try to open your page with leadid as parameter:
yourInstanceUrl/apex/youpage?id=[leadID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot have an attachment object created without assigning a parentId

Create a lead record first

```
public PageReference UploadFile(){
Id leadId ;
if(recId == null){
  lead l  = new lead();
  l.lastname = '';//Ask business what should be lead record name
  insert l;
   leadId = l.Id;
}
PageReference pgRef;
if(fileBody != null && fileName != null)
{
  Attachment myAttachment  = new Attachment();
  myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
  myAttachment.Name = fileName;
  myAttachment.ParentId = leadId;
  insert myAttachment;
   pgRef = new PageReference('/' + myAttachment.Id);
   pgRef.setRedirect(true);
   return pgRef;
  }
   return null;
 }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Ilya Lepesh. Thanks for the heads up concerning the parentId Mohith. Let me try the solution you provided and will update you. Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I am getting an error on the line below:   `l.lastname = '';` I am getting Compile Error: Variable does not exist:lastname, I tried to camel case it but it still pops up

Comment: lead l  = new lead(); This should have defined lead var

Comment: the variable that is not being recognised is the lastname. I have modified as follows ** public PageReference UploadFile(){
        Id leadId ;
        if(recId == null){        
            Lead l = new Lead(); 
            l.lastname= 'test';
            insert l;
            leadId = l.Id;
        }** but am still getting the error

Comment: Did it compiled now ? Also you cannot name as 'Test' for lead record .It will get your marketing folks guessing .Figure out with business what you want to call the bucketted lead

Comment: Thank you for the assistance but, no it did not compile it is still giving out the error." Variable does not exist: lastname" I am using `Test` as I am still working on the sandbox currently.

Comment: Where are you saving this ? In IDE or directly server ?

Comment: I am saving on the server, I am still learning salesforce please kindly bear with me

Comment: Screenshot the error please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to add pics but here is the error word for word:  "Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: lastname at line 21 column 13" and line 21 contains the following `l.lastname= 'test';`

Comment: can you change l to lnew and see if error persists.

Comment: changed it but it is still giving an error on `lastname'

Comment: Is your profile admin and do you have FLS for lead object properly set

Comment: I am on the admin profile